# skystar hd2 driver issue

Tags: dvb

I recently installed a skystar hd2 card in my box. I have drivers loaded, everything seems good to go but i cant tune.

When I attempt to run w_scan (from apt-get, w_scan version 20130331, compiled for DVB API 5.10) I receive srate errors.
 Specifically:

```
# w_scan -fs -s S93W1 US -k > a.conf
w_scan version 20130331 (compiled for DVB API 5.10)
using settings for 93.1 west Galaxy 25
scan type SATELLITE, channellist 111
output format kaffeine channels.dvb
WARNING: could not guess your codepage. Falling back to 'UTF-8'
output charset 'UTF-8', use -C <charset> to override
Info: using DVB adapter auto detection.
/dev/dvb/adapter0/frontend0 -> SATELLITE "STB0899 Multistandard": very good :-))

Using SATELLITE frontend (adapter /dev/dvb/adapter0/frontend0)
-_-_-_-_ Getting frontend capabilities-_-_-_-_ 
Using DVB API 5.a
frontend 'STB0899 Multistandard' supports
INVERSION_AUTO
DVB-S
DVB-S2
FREQ (0.95GHz ... 2.15GHz)
SRATE (5.000MSym/s ... 45.000MSym/s)
using LNB "UNIVERSAL"
-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_ 
trying 'S  f = 11780 kHz V SR = 30000  5/6 0,35  QPSK'
(time: 00:01) 
trying 'S  f = 11874 kHz H SR = 19510  3/4 0,35  QPSK'
(time: 00:04) 
trying 'S  f = 11890 kHz H SR =  3000  3/4 0,35  QPSK'
(time: 00:08)   skipped: (srate 3000000 unsupported by driver)

initial_tune:2271: Setting frontend failed S  f = 11890 kHz H SR =  3000  3/4 0,35  QPSK
trying 'S  f = 11915 kHz H SR =  4350  3/4 0,35  QPSK'
(time: 00:08)   skipped: (srate 4350000 unsupported by driver)

initial_tune:2271: Setting frontend failed S  f = 11915 kHz H SR =  4350  3/4 0,35  QPSK
trying 'S  f = 11996 kHz V SR =  3650  3/4 0,35  QPSK'
(time: 00:09)   skipped: (srate 3650000 unsupported by driver)

initial_tune:2271: Setting frontend failed S  f = 11996 kHz V SR =  3650  3/4 0,35  QPSK

ERROR: Sorry - i couldn't get any working frequency/transponder
 Nothing to scan!!
#
```

Couldnt find a way to configure the srate for my card.

When I run kaffeine to tune and scan for channels (I have it configured it to scan with the same satellite settings):

```
kaffeine(10272) DvbLinuxDevice::tune: ioctl FE_SET_FRONTEND failed for frontend "/dev/dvb/adapter0/frontend0" 
kaffeine(10272) DvbLinuxDevice::tune: ioctl FE_SET_FRONTEND failed for frontend "/dev/dvb/adapter0/frontend0" 
kaffeine(10272) DvbLinuxDevice::tune: ioctl FE_SET_FRONTEND failed for frontend "/dev/dvb/adapter0/frontend0" 
kaffeine(10272) DvbLinuxDevice::tune: ioctl FE_SET_FRONTEND failed for frontend "/dev/dvb/adapter0/frontend0" 
kaffeine(10272) DvbLinuxDevice::tune: ioctl FE_SET_FRONTEND failed for frontend "/dev/dvb/adapter0/frontend0" 
kaffeine(10272) DvbLinuxDevice::tune: ioctl FE_SET_FRONTEND failed for frontend "/dev/dvb/adapter0/frontend0" 
kaffeine(10272) DvbLinuxDevice::tune: ioctl FE_SET_FRONTEND failed for frontend "/dev/dvb/adapter0/frontend0" 
kaffeine(10272) DvbLinuxDevice::tune: ioctl FE_SET_FRONTEND failed for frontend "/dev/dvb/adapter0/frontend0" 
kaffeine(10272) DvbLinuxDevice::tune: ioctl FE_SET_FRONTEND failed for frontend "/dev/dvb/adapter0/frontend0" 
kaffeine(10272) DvbLinuxDevice::tune: ioctl FE_SET_FRONTEND failed for frontend "/dev/dvb/adapter0/frontend0"
```

I have no idea why the frontend would fail.

**SPECS**

- I have a skystar HD2 installed in a pc running Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS
  with kernel 3.19.0-25-generic.
- I live in the US so I'm using the Galaxy 25 Satellite
- I compiled the latest v4l-dvb source and rebooted to load its modules (followed the instructions [here](http://www.linuxtv.org/wiki/index.php/How_to_Obtain,_Build_and_Install_V4L-DVB_Device_Drivers) to the **T**), built installed dvb-apps and szap-s2.

Some more diagnostics:

```
# ls /dev/dvb
adapter0
# ls /dev/dvb/adapter0
demux0  dvr0  frontend0  net0
#
```

I just want to be able to tune and sniff some DVB-S channels w/o having to work on a Windows box